# Drupal 8 node serialization to JSON

Tags: 8

I am trying to use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid) to store a node object in a variable and pass the variable into drupal 8's serialization component or even symphony's serialization methods. All my efforts have resulted in a JSON object that is only encoding the first property of the node which is {"in_preview":null}.

For example the following callback returns {"in_preview":null}

```
public function page(){

  $nrm = new \Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
  $node = Node::load(2);
  $json = $nrm -> encode($node, 'json');

  return $json;

}
```

What class/method would accomplish serialization of $node in the above code?

Comment: Maybe $node->toArray() is what you're looking for? also you should return JsonResponse in this case.

Comment: agree with @user21641 json return is better than using a serializer

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use the `serializer` service if you want to serialize a Drupal data type ([Typed Data API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1794140)) so that normalization is run properly. This requires enabling the serialization module as pointed out by Alari Truuts, which defines the `serializer` service.

The serialize method is a little confusing as to what the `$context` parameter means. For Drupal Typed Data, it requires the plugin id of the data type ([EntityAdapter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Plugin!DataType!EntityAdapter.php/class/EntityAdapter/8) in this case).

```
$serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
$node = Node::load(2);
$data = $serializer->serialize($node, 'json', ['plugin_id' => 'entity']);
```

Comment: When trying to use the serializer as a service I get the following error: "Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "serializer". in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 157 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php)."

Comment: Apparently it makes sense to first enable the serialization module where the service and classes are in :) (Leaving this here in case someone else stumples upon this)

Comment: Thank you much for your answer, it helps a lot

Comment: Don't forget to use use **return new Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($build); **

Comment: If you need to return this JSON directly from your controller use the following JSON response:

`return JsonResponse::fromJsonString($data);`