# How do I find all objects under an object?

Tags: nodes, 8

When I try to print out the possible options of `Node::load(10)`

I just get null. But I know that there are options as `Node::load(10)->field_name->value` gives the value of the field.

I have tried using dpm as well as json_encode.

examples:

```
dpm(Node::load(10)->getFieldDefinitions());
dpm(Node::load(10)->toArray());
json_encode(Node::load(10))
```

Comment: why not serialize the node ?? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191419/drupal-8-node-serialization-to-json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following command, and it returns the expected output.

```
drush php-eval 'var_export(\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1));'
```

The only case where I get `NULL` as output is when I pass to `Node::load()` a node ID that doesn't exist.

The fact `Node::load()` loads the data from the database doesn't matter; in fact, the method still returns an object of the `Node` class.

```
Drupal\node\Entity\Node::__set_state(array(
   'in_preview' => NULL,
   'values' => 
  array (
    'vid' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'langcode' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => 'en',
    ),
    'revision_timestamp' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1465363710',
    ),
    'revision_uid' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'revision_log' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => NULL,
    ),
    'nid' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'type' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => 'page',
    ),
    'uuid' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '88E2D589-473B-4FE9-9A5A-F1F768A5E4E8',
    ),
    'isDefaultRevision' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'title' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => 'Test',
    ),
    'uid' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'status' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'created' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1465363684',
    ),
    'changed' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1465363710',
    ),
    'promote' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '0',
    ),
    'sticky' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '0',
    ),
    'revision_translation_affected' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'default_langcode' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'body' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'value' => '<p>Test.</p>
',
          'summary' => '',
          'format' => 'basic_html',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
   'fields' => 
  array (
  ),
   'fieldDefinitions' => NULL,
   'languages' => NULL,
   'langcodeKey' => 'langcode',
   'defaultLangcodeKey' => 'default_langcode',
   'activeLangcode' => 'x-default',
   'defaultLangcode' => 'en',
   'translations' => 
  array (
    'x-default' => 
    array (
      'status' => 1,
    ),
  ),
   'translationInitialize' => false,
   'newRevision' => false,
   'isDefaultRevision' => '1',
   'entityKeys' => 
  array (
    'bundle' => 'page',
    'id' => '1',
    'revision' => '1',
    'uuid' => '88E2D589-473B-4FE9-9A5A-F1F768A5E4E8',
  ),
   'translatableEntityKeys' => 
  array (
    'label' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => 'Test',
    ),
    'langcode' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => 'en',
    ),
    'status' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'uid' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
    'default_langcode' => 
    array (
      'x-default' => '1',
    ),
  ),
   'validated' => false,
   'validationRequired' => false,
   'entityTypeId' => 'node',
   'enforceIsNew' => NULL,
   'typedData' => NULL,
   'cacheContexts' => 
  array (
  ),
   'cacheTags' => 
  array (
  ),
   'cacheMaxAge' => -1,
   '_serviceIds' => 
  array (
  ),
))
```

Even running `drush php-eval 'var_export(\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1)->toArray());'` (i.e. using the `toArray()` method you tried) gave me an output different from `NULL`. In this case, using a node ID that doesn't exist, you get a *Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object* error.

```
array (
  'nid' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1',
    ),
  ),
  'uuid' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '994535DB-7C4E-42F2-94CE-576DA3E9FC0B',
    ),
  ),
  'vid' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1',
    ),
  ),
  'langcode' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'en',
    ),
  ),
  'type' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'target_id' => 'page',
    ),
  ),
  'title' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => 'Test',
    ),
  ),
  'uid' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'target_id' => '1',
    ),
  ),
  'status' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1',
    ),
  ),
  'created' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1466285938',
    ),
  ),
  'changed' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1466285973',
    ),
  ),
  'promote' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '0',
    ),
  ),
  'sticky' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '0',
    ),
  ),
  'revision_timestamp' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1466285973',
    ),
  ),
  'revision_uid' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'target_id' => '1',
    ),
  ),
  'revision_log' => 
  array (
  ),
  'revision_translation_affected' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1',
    ),
  ),
  'default_langcode' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '1',
    ),
  ),
  'path' => 
  array (
  ),
  'body' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'value' => '<p>Testing a Drupal function.</p>
',
      'summary' => '',
      'format' => 'basic_html',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Also, remember to fully qualify the class with its namespace, or add a `use \Drupal\node\Entity\Node;` line before using the class.

Using `drush php-eval 'print json_encode(\Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load(1));'` I just get `{"in_preview":null}` because `json_encode()` doesn't prints out all the object properties.

Comment: While techncially correct, the data you receive with this pretty useless and huge, due to injected objects and references. Just use $node->toArray() and dump that. See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200046/8-nodeload-is-generating-an-object-with-circular-reference-which-is-crashing/200118#200118 and similar questions